# How to merge part files in HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, parquet

## What I want

I have 17TB of date-partitioned data in the directory of this kind:

```
/data_folder
  /date=2021.01.01
    /part-00002-f0b91523-6e0c-4adc-88cc-e9451614791d.c000.snappy.parquet
    /part-00002-f0193442-c20e-49d2-bde1-70053ae2a254.c000.snappy.parquet
    /... over 9000 part files 
  /date=2021.01.02
    /part-00002-bdb50c33-fd32-4e87-9edb-cec77973760b.c000.snappy.parquet
    /part-00001-e2cd906e-5669-46d7-92e9-7498ed60487f.c000.snappy.parquet
    /... over 9000 part files
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
/data_folder
  /date=2021.01.01
    /merge.parquet
  /date=2021.01.02
    /merge.parquet
```

I want this for the reason that I heard that HDFS is preferable to store a small number of large files, instead of a large number of small files. Now my queries have become very slow. Hope this optimization will speed them up

## What I do

So I run the commands like this:

```
hdfs dfs -getmerge /data_folder/date=2021.01.01 merge.parquet;
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal -f -t 4 merge.parquet /merged/date=2021.01.01/merge.parquet;
```

I got the directory structure I wanted, but now I can't read the files. The query:

```
%spark2.spark

val date = "2021.01.01"


val ofdCheques2Uniq = spark.read
    .parquet(s"/projects/khajiit/data/OfdCheques2/date=$date")
    .withColumn("chequeId", concat($"content.cashboxRegNumber", lit("_"), $"content.number", lit("_"), col("content.timestamp")))
    .dropDuplicates("chequeId")
    
val ofdChequesTempUniq = spark.read
    .parquet(s"/projects/khajiit/data/OfdChequesTemp/date=$date")
    .withColumn("chequeId", concat($"content.cashboxRegNumber", lit("_"), $"content.number", lit("_"), col("content.timestamp")))
    .dropDuplicates("chequeId")

println(s"OfdCheques2   : ${ofdCheques2Uniq.count} unique cheques")
println(s"OfdChequesTemp: ${ofdChequesTempUniq.count} unique cheques")
```

Prints:

```
OfdCheques2   : 4309 unique cheques
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 74.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 74.0 (TID 1720, srs-st-hdp-s3.dev.kontur.ru, executor 1): java.io.IOException: can not read class org.apache.parquet.format.PageHeader: don't know what type: 13
```

Meanwhile, such a query:

```
val ofdCheques2Uniq = spark.read
    .parquet(s"/projects/khajiit/data/OfdCheques2/date=$date")
    
val ofdChequesTempUniq = spark.read
    .parquet(s"/projects/khajiit/data/OfdChequesTemp/date=$date")

println(s"OfdCheques2   : ${ofdCheques2Uniq.count} unique cheques")
println(s"OfdChequesTemp: ${ofdChequesTempUniq.count} unique cheques")
```

Prints:

```
OfdCheques2   : 5290 unique cheques
OfdChequesTemp: 18 unique cheques
```

## Finally the questions

1. Is the `getmerge` command applicable to my problem? If so, what did I do wrong?
2. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: I assume that I forgot to copy the files describing the data format. The problem is that I don't know where they are stored or if they even exist

Comment: You shouldn't need to merge them because almost all Hadoop FS APIs can read whole directory paths

Comment: And, no, `getmerge` doesn't address the problem because you're effectively copying TB worth of data into one machine, then re-uploading it (wont work when your client machine only has few GB of disk space)

Comment: > You shouldn't need to merge them because almost all Hadoop FS APIs can read whole directory paths

@OneCricketeer but a large number of files can overload NameNode. I want to eliminate this overload

Comment: The proper solution is to fix the process that actually generated the files to begin with. Or if these are streaming data, then batch the files somewhere else first, such as within Apache NiFi

Comment: > wont work when your client machine only has few GB of disk space

Not a problem. Each folder (date) is just a couple of gigabytes

Comment: @OneCricketeer, yes, that would be the most correct. The problem is that the data comes in chaotically. A check for 2016 may come now, in 2021. And there are many such checks, which is why ~ 6000 files accumulate in each folder

Comment: If timeseries data is coming in, an actual TSDB would make more sense than Hadoop. Or Druid/Pinot. Also, you would want to track time of ingestion, not just the record date itself.

Comment: I agree with you. But is there TSDB with exactly-once delivery support? I wanted to use ClickHouse instead of HDFS, but it did not fit for this reason

Comment: Kafka consumers can be configured with EOS support, but any downstream systems cannot control duplicates without proper indicies, AFAIK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> got the directory structure I wanted, but now I can't read the files

This is due to the binary structure of Parquet files. They have header/footer metadata that stores the schemas and the number of records in the file... `getmerge` therefore is really only useful for row-delimited, non-binary data formats.

What you can do instead is have `spark.read.path("/data_folder")`, then `repartition` or `coalesce` that dataframe, then output to a new "merged" output location

Another alternative is Gobbilin - https://gobblin.apache.org/docs/user-guide/Compaction/